Assign Type To A Variable Based On The Value Of Another Variable
I want to do something like this:
document("post").insert({ ... } /* TYPE SHOULD BE AUTOMATICALLY DETERMINED BY TYPESCRIPT */ ); 

The document() function returns an object containing functions such as insert, the object also contains a document property which is assigned the value of the argument passed to document() function. The object has a type of DocumentObject and functions like insert can access document propery using this.document. Everything is working fine but I want insert to accept an argument of a certain type determined by the value of this.document.
How can I have parameters that have types that vary based on the value of another variable. This is the declaration of insert:
export default async function (this: DocumentObject, record: ???): Promise<...> {...}

The variable this.document (which can be accessed from the function body) can contain the following values: post, user, comment. I also have respective types for each possible value: Post, User, Comment. This is howthis.document is defined:
document: "post" | "comment" | "user" = ...;

My Question Is: How can I use Typescript to map each value to its respective type, so I can assign that type to record parameter? Is this even possible in Typescript?
Note: Not a duplicate of Conditional parameter type based on another parameters' value, and Conditional type based on the value of another key; They suggested I use function overloads, is there another way to do that?

Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] where we can copy and paste it into our own IDEs and immediately get to work on it.  Currently we have to write our own Post, User, and Comment types, etc.  And whatever the  Promise<> output type is.

(see prev comment) Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Oh yeah, that works perfectly, exactly what I wanted!

I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

First you probably want to write a mapping interface that represents the relationship between the document property and the acceptable type for the insert argument:
interface DocumentMap {
    post: Post;
    user: User;
    comment: Comment;
}

Once we do that, we could make DocumentObject generic in the type K of the document property like this:
interface DocumentObject<K extends keyof DocumentMap> {
    document: K;
    insert(record: DocumentMap[K]): Promise<any>;
}

Here K is constrained to keyof DocumentMap which is just the union type "post" | "user" | "comment" as desired.  And then the insert() method accepts a record argument of the indexed access type DocumentMap[K].
Finally your document function is generic in the type K of its argument, and returns a value of type DocumentObject<K>:
declare function document<K extends keyof DocumentMap>(k: K): DocumentObject<K>;

Let's test it out:
document("post").insert(post); // okay
document("user").insert(user); // okay
document("comment").insert(comment); // okay
document("user").insert(post); // error

Looks good. When you call document("user") you get a DocumentObject<"user">, which is of type {document: "user", insert(record: User): Promise<any>}, so the insert() method accepts a User and rejects a Post.
Playground link to code

You can declare an additional type that maps the document key to the intended types, and use generics in your function to create the association with indexed types
type PostDoc = {author: string}
type UserDoc = {name:string}
type CommentDoc = {text:string}

type DocumentObject = {
  document:"post"|"user"|"comment"
}

type DocumentTypes = {
  post: PostDoc,
  user: UserDoc,
  comment:CommentDoc
} 

async function insert<D extends DocumentObject, R extends DocumentTypes[D["document"]]>(doc:D, record:R) {
    ...
}

Then the type of the second parameter is dependent on the value of the document field.
insert({document:"post"}, {author:"a"})
insert({document:"user"}, {name:"b"})
insert({document:"comment"}, {text:"c"})
insert({document:"comment"}, {name:"d"}) // TypeError
insert({document:"user"}, {author:"e"}) // TypeError


It looks like you misunderstood my code, the this 'parameter' in the function is not a parameter that should be substituted with an argument; instead, it's how this keyword is typed. Btw it's called 'Fake This'. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions. Anyways, will this work if this wasn't a parameter to be passed into? Like, will this work: document("user").insert({ name: "a" })?
